# How to Show Lookups using Silverlight 4.0 and RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a relational database lets say it consist of an Employee's Table and Department's table and an EmployeesType Table.

The employee's table has a DepartmentId, EmployeeTypeId foreign Keys

and now I created a silverlight app with an entity data model and generated a domain service class

and now I want to  show employees info in a grid .. of course I can't show Department name and EmployeeType Name in the Grid

I have to use the Include Data annotation in my metadata ..

I did this .. but how can I show all the included fields in one query?

I used this

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesWithDepartments()
{
      return this.ObjectContext.Employees.Include("Department.EmployeesType");
}
```

but I managed to show departments **only**..  **What About the other foreign keys?**

**How can I add them to my query?**

Comment: Please don't SHOUT, __bold__ is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys .. so after two freaking days of trial and error .. i finally found it

here is what you should do ..

in your  getEmployees Method or whatever method of retrival you use  you can include all your forign keys as follow

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesWithDepartments() 
{ 
      return this.ObjectContext.Employees.Include("Department").Include("EmployeeType"); 
}
```

and so on for every forgin key you have included in your metadata class

then in the front end you can now have access to the Department Property and use the Binding syntax to bind it with your View

as follow:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Department.DepartmentName"/>
```

Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to Employee - you access Department id something like:

```
{Binding Employee.Department.Id}
```

And you access EmployeeType like

```
{Binding Employee.EmployeesType.Id}
```

Is that what you asking?

Comment: Not Exactly in RIA Services you cant accees second level objects like this without including them ..which i did.. but i dont know what is the best way to present them in my grid which uses the GetEmployeesWithDepartments() 
to prsent data .. so my question again is what should i write on this method to get all info about all forigin keys ??